# What is the best way for communication between Powershell script and Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, powershell

There is a windows service written in c#. I like to run Powershell scripts on the same machine and to be able to exchange information between this windows service and PS scripts. So I'm wondering what is the best, easy, simple and efficient way?
WCF?

Comment: You run PS scripts manually, or windows service executes that script?

Comment: It depends; give us some more context.

Comment: Named pipes is one option among many others.

Comment: PS scripts run locally but they are invoked from a remote machine.

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about named pipes, but wanted to hear gurus before implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, if both intercommunicating processes run on the same machine I would consider communication using named pipes.

Comment: Oh, missed comments that propose named pipes :)

Answer (score 4):

I propose following ways which I used:

1. File system
   I use file system for cases if I need to make simple read/write operations. As usually I wrote something to file. And then appended to file time from the time. The biggest issue with this approach is locking mechanism.
2. Clipboard 
   this is mostly fitting to cases if I need send some small chunk of information to clipboard, and windows service with regular interval read it. Big fragments of text work slowly, but small bits of text are fine. Among negative facets of clipboard are issues related to interfering with user copy something to clipboard. In order to fix this I used separated account for service
3. WCF 
   Mainly I've used this option for distributed systems. Personally I don't see benefit from it if PS and windows service run on the same machine. But there is nothing wrong if to have on the same machine both of them.
4. Sockets 
   I like this option for cases if I need quickly pass information through memory quickly.
5. Windows Event Log ( ugly idea, but for some cases useful ). 
   As usually this is good for notification about errors or some information activities.
6. Database ( Some time it's also workable )
   If passing information has a lot of formatting, complicated rules of reading, then I prefer to make some classes, which can be reused by PS as .Net objects, and read/write/modify them in windows service.

Comment: I have been looking toward WCF. Could you add more details about what type of communication you used?

Comment: I've extended my answer little bit more